# How to change current working directory in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

How to change current working directory in VS Code?

Let's say, I have a parent folder called apps and inside it I have a child folder called MyBeautifulApp and I opened the apps folder using vscode. What command sould I run on the commandline to not only `cd` into MyBeautifulApp but also change the directory so that it seems like I opened MyBeautifulApp using VS Code and did not just `cd` into it?

Answer (score 8):

In `File` select `Close Folder`, and you will go back to the main menu, where you can select a new folder as the new working directory.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to change the cwd using the File Explorer. This is the correct aproach to date.

Answer (score 4):

Just close Visual Studio Code and open it in the right folder again.

*close program*

`code MyBeautifulApp/`

**OR**

Press `Command` + `O` and open your folder.

Comment: Thank you. This I know. I just wanted a way that I do not have to close VS Code.