# how to change current directory (cd command in VScode) GITLAB

Tags: git, github, directory, gitlab, git-branch

I have cloned a repository to my vscode, and before starting to work on the assignment I was given, I have created a branch using `git branch`

```
(branch-name)`
```

now, I finished the first assignment (milestone1 is the name of the first assignment branch I assigned), and now I want to add it, and then commit and start a new branch and work on the second assignment I was given, but I have an error.
the error is:

```
`fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`
```

what should I do next?
Thanks!

### what I have tried:

I have tried to change the current directory without the right command.

I have tried to search for the right command on google with no success.
I have tried to use

```
`git help -g
```

for more commands and maybe solve this on my own.

and I need to follow the assignment deadlines so I have no more time to spend on it.

can someone help me solve this issue or point me in the right direction?

### What I was expecting?

when I type

```
`cd -`
```

and click the

```
`TAB`
```

key, to be able to see the directory I need to go to when I am trying to type part of the dir name.. but I had no such option.

Comment: Are you trying to change the directory on your local file system?

Comment: what do you mean by local file system?
I want to change the directory to js-fibonacci-01-AsafDanan/   (when js-Fibonacci-01) is the vscode assignment folder I recieved when I cloned it from the GitHub repository

Comment: maybe this link is useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029787/how-to-change-current-working-directory-in-vs-code

Comment: @ninebee not helpful.. anything else?